# Is it possible to have 2 different S3 buckets as an active-active Cloudfront origin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to optimize the performance of a S3 static website. Cloudfront helps a lot with caching. But for the first request of each resource it still takes up to 1 second to retrieve a small webpage stored on thousands of miles away.

I found a hacky solution to have my website replicated in multi region S3 buckets, but it's not optimal since it requires redirects: https://medium.com/@jaderd/10x-faster-aws-s3-static-websites-28c0a2a8cea5

I'm looking for a solution similar to Amazon S3 Multi-Region Access Points, but that seems incompatible with Cloudfront. Global Accelerator also sounds good but it seems incompatible with S3.

Comment: Does r53 geo based routing help?

Comment: If you want a solutions 'similar' to Amazon S3 Multi-Region Access Points, then why not use it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Amazon S3 Multi-Region Access Points seems incompatible with Cloudfront. Global Accelerator seems incompatible with S3.

Comment: There would be no sense in mixing the two. Amazon CloudFront is the ideal service to cache static content closer to distributed users. Multi-Region Access Points is probably better-suited for programmatic access (eg copies of data closer to processing). I don't see why you'd want to combine the two.

Comment: "Global Accelerator also sounds good but it seems incompatible with S3." -- If you use MRAP for active/active S3 buckets, then it uses Global Accelerator to route to the optimal bucket (more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws/articles/76250275/always-on-access-for-your-data-in-amazon-s3-using-cross-region-replication-and)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein you'd combine them to speed up access time on a cache miss.

Comment: You can't point CloudFront directly at MRAP but there's a recipe for how to do it here: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-with-s3-multi-region-access-points